# How to prevent read access for only node or some keys in realtime database firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to prevent read access for only one node.

let's assume I have nodes like that

```
"0" : {
//somedata
},
"1": {
//somedata
},
"2": {
//somedata
},
"3": {
 //my private data
}
```

Now I won't want "3" to be read from any connections. What rules should be written there to prevent its read and write access?

I tried using rules like:-

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$3": {
        ".read": false,
      }
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth!=null && auth.uid == 'myuid'",
  }
}
```

If I do this then in the child_added it gives me all nodes also changing "$3" to "3" doesn't matter right now

```
  {
     "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": "auth!=null && auth.uid == 'myuid'",
       "$3": {
           ".read": false,
        }
     }
  }
```

the second one gives all nodes because in the very first line of the rule I used the read key as true i.e working on the cascading rule as .read and .write rules work from top-down from firebase docs [Firebase Rules Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data)

If any suggestions for the same or different approach I need to do this, please suggest me that?
Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 1):

You were close. As you read correctly, the rules cascade from higher tiers down to the more specific ones. So if you approve the write at a higher tier (as you did for the root of your database) that "allowed" write permission applies to your entire database.

The `$` is used to [identify a variable name in the path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments). So when you use `"$3"` you are actually defining a variable named `"$3"`, not referencing the specific key `"3"`. What you are looking to do is specify a variable that is used for all values that aren't `"3"`, which by convention, is called `"$other"`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "3": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": false
    },
    "$other": { // any key not named above at this level  
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth!=null && auth.uid == 'myuid'"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I implement this, I didn't get any data

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "3": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false,
      }
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth!=null && auth.uid == 'myuid'",
  }
}
```

1st you are checking, if the data is "3", block it and return. If not check below rules (in this case, allow authenticated users).

Comment: This one not working, it's giving me all nodes, I don't want all the nodes